# Not getting proper table in latex

Tags: tables

### Please help me draw this table

### |             P1                  |              P2                |

### | s1 |  s2 |s3    | s4     | s5   | s6 |   s7 |  s8  |  s9  | s10  |

This is how i tried, but i am not able to get proper line

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{HI}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}}
%\begin{small}
\resizebox{9cm}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cline{1-1}   \multicolumn{5}{c|}{A}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ B}\\
\cline{2-5} \cline{6-8}
%\hline
 h & N1 & M1 & Avg1 & Reqd.P & M2  &  Avg2 &  reqd.P & optimal P \\
\hline
1 & 5 & 2 & 4.75 & 1 & 3 & 4.50 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
2 & 13 & 6 & 12.34 & 2 & 7 & 11.7 & 2 & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{small}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The vertical lines should be avoided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way, with `booktabs` (no vertical rules) and `siunitx` (alignment on the decimal dot in columns 4 and 7). Not sure why you use `\resizebox`, so I removed it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{HI}\label{mytable}
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}S[table-format=2.2]cc S[table-format=2.2]cc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ B}\tabularnewline
    \cmidrule(lr){1-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    h & N1 & M1 & {Avg1} & Reqd. P & M2 & {Avg2} & Reqd. P & Optimal P \tabularnewline
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    1 & 5 & 2 & 4.75 & 1 & 3 & 4.50 & 1 & 1\tabularnewline
    2 & 13 & 6 & 12.34 & 2 & 7 & 11.7 & 2 & 2\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]